# visual studio 2017 html tag selector

Tags: html, visual-studio, editor, visual-studio-2017

I'm looking for the tag selector that visual studio 2013 has but visual studio 2017 does not have or I just cant find the extension.

[image]

in the bottom right part of the image you can see the tags hierarchically and on click, dropdown pops up with "select tag", "select tag content" etc...

Now I cant find this on 2017 and I'm nearly having an hearth attack or cancer or sth.

where is that functionality on vs2017???

Answer (score 4):

I've found the solution.

just navigate through

**Tools > Options > Text Editor > Html > advanced**

and set **Enable Tag Navigator -> TRUE**

jeez that has to be standard

Comment: I agree. it should be enabled by default. Noticed the same issue when opening .chtml files