# Where is the tag navigator in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I've searched everywhere but can't find how to turn on the tag navigator in VS2019.  Does anyone know how?

Comment: The settings that existed for VS2017 (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247667/visual-studio-2017-html-tag-selector)) are not there for VS2019. This is not a good sign.

Comment: According to [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/891719/view.html), they are working on a new feature to replace the old tag navigator.

Answer (score 0):

The tag navigator was removed in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Excellent question. If I had the answer, it would get 100+ upvotes.